# Gradle throws could not find method add() on "gradle wrapper" command

Tags: gradle, artifactory, tooltwist

I'm trying to run **"gradle {task}"** command in my project but this error keeps on showing.

```
$ gradle {task}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/myAccount/Development/Tooltwist-8.3.1/myProjectName/build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':myProjectName'.
Could not find method add() for arguments [artifactoryPublish, class org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.extractor.BuildInfoTask] on task set.
```

It doesn't matter what task I'm trying to run (build, jar, etc).

Any inputs will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused by using the wrong version of Gradle. Probably you are using version 2.0+, but your build script is for pre-v2.0.

The best way to avoid this is to use the Gradle wrapper if it is there in your project (look for a file named *gradlew* in your project directory). If it doesn't exist, run these commands to create it.

```
$ mkdir ,gw
$ cd ,gw
$ echo "task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '1.12' }" > build.gradle
$ gradle wrapper
$ ls -l
total 32
-rw-r--r--  1 philipcallender  wheel    55 26 Aug 09:56 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x  3 philipcallender  wheel   102 26 Aug 09:55 gradle
-rwxr-xr-x  1 philipcallender  wheel  5080 26 Aug 09:55 gradlew
-rw-r--r--  1 philipcallender  wheel  2404 26 Aug 09:55 gradlew.bat
$ mv gradle* ..
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf ,gw
```

These new files should be checked into version control (e.g. Github) for other developers to use. You can now build with Gradle, ensuring the correct version is used, by using the `gradlew` command in place of `gradle`. For example:

```
$ gradlew jar
```

Depending upon your $PATH environment variable, you might need to run:

```
$ ./gradlew jar
```

Comment: The same solution worked for the similar problem "Could not find method create() for arguments [artifactoryPublish, class org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.task.BuildInfoPublicationsTask] on task set."

Comment: ok, so how do you fix it if you are getting it and you are already using gradlew?